# И снова прогресс скроллинга страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Прогресс скроллинга прикручен, но нужно чтобы он начинался не с самого начала скролла, а спустя 900 пикселов. Код как ниже работает, но он спустя 900 px показывает прогресс *уже* проскролленой страницы, а нужно чтобы начиналось как будто с ноля. Надеюсь понятно изложил. Большое спасибо Елене :)

```
var bar = $('#bar'),
    $window = $(window),
    docHeight = $(document).height(),
    winHeight = $window.height(),
    baseX = docHeight - winHeight;

$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop() > 900) {
       $window.scroll(function(e) { 
           var x = ($window.scrollTop() / baseX ) * 100;
           bar.css({'width': + x + '%'});
       });
   } else {
       return;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того чтобы получить необходимый результат нужно немного изменить формулу, а именно ввести в нее сдвиг на необходимое количество px. В результате получим такую формулу:

```
x = (scroll - shift) / (height - shift) ) * 100
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kison/0hhLqbnp/)

```
var bar = $('#bar'),    
    $window = $(window),
    docHeight = $(document).height(),
    winHeight = $window.height(),
    baseX = docHeight - winHeight,
    shift = 900;

$(window).scroll(function(){       
   if($(window).scrollTop() > shift) {         
       $window.scroll(function(e) { 
           var x = (($window.scrollTop() - shift) / (baseX - shift) ) * 100;
           bar.css({'width': + x + '%'});
       });
   } else {
       return;
   }
});
```

Comment: Дело не в этом. Мне нужно, чтобы прогресс именно начинался с 900px, а не с начала страницы. В представленном коде он действительно начинается не с начала страницы, а с 900px, НО отображает даже эти 900px прогресса, а нужно, чтобы он с этой точки стартовал, то есть с ноля отображался

Comment: Неправильно Вас понял изначально, внес изменения в ответ

Comment: Я уже нашел решение, причем формула аналогична. Но всё равно спасибо